# Is there any library in java that helps to create custom query language like SQL?

Tags: java

I need a library that can invoke some commands (operations) by parsing query string.

e.g. Say we have string like this: *"get chat 0,100", "send message to user id=25 text='Hello'"*, etc.
The first example gets rows from 0 to 100 from the table called chats from the database and the second one sends message with the text "Hello" to the user whose id is 25.

I am not going to use this only for accessing the database. Otherwise I would just make some DAO instead.

It is possible to realize by writing own library from scratch, but before doing this I wanted to know if there any ready one. I thought somebody already faced this kind of problem for sure.

Comment: ANTLR comes to mind

Comment: It's best to write it from scratch, mainly because you can output more informative error messages when something goes wrong. Recursive descent parsers are very simple, and if there's an error it's not hard to guess what the user meant.

Comment: You can also use SQL with Apache Calcite

Answer (score -3):

You can use [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/)

c3p0 is a Java library for JDBC drivers with JNDI-bindable DataSources, including DataSources that implement Connection and Statement Pooling, as described by the jdbc3 spec and jdbc2 std extension.

Comment: How can this library be of any help to what the user wants to do?

Comment: That is for Connection pooling, isn't it? How will that be of any use to this requirement at all?

Comment: downvoted as c3p0 doesn't help in creating a query language, but is rather responsible for automated connection pooling.